# Is it possible to add superscript to browser tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am being asked to add superscript to the text that appears in a browser tab.

The tab always shows the the contents of the `<title>` tag so does anybody know if this is in fact possible?

Comment: Don't think so. You can't have any styling in there as far as I know.

Comment: No styling inside `<title>` tab, however, any UTF-8 characters (and symbols) are accepted.

Comment: Did you see my answer before accepting "No, it's not possible" answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The tab text is the document title, and doesn't support HTML in any browser I've ever seen.

You could get the HTML entity code for a few superscript numbers (`&#178` is superscript 2), I suppose.

Comment: They aren't numbers unfortunately - the letters MC are required

Comment: Then you can't. "Don't make it work the way it should, let it work the way it does," as they say. Maybe you could get the same UX with a scrolling tab title, or even (gasp) blinking?

Comment: Just tried with the entity code -- doesn't work (in Chrome, anyway). You could just paste in the character to your javascript (`$("title").text("E=mc²")`), but as other posters have pointed out, that would require that the browser use a font with that character mapping. And mobile browsers mostly don't show the tab title in the basic UI at all.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is that you cannot use any markup in a `title` element (this is not just a formal requirement—browsers do not recognize any markup there), so you are limited to what can be done in plain text. There is a relatively large set of [superscript characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) in Unicode, but they have been added according to specific use in various contexts rather than systematically adding superscript versions of characters. Moreover, support to most of these characters in fonts is rather limited, and browsers may render `title` element using a specific font that you cannot change (as an author).

Regarding the specific question mentioned in a comment, about letters MC, there is a superscript M character, though it is meant for use in phonetic notations, and there is no superscript C character.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what characters you want to put in the superscript. If there are Unicode superscript characters for what you want to display, try something like:

```
<head>
    <title>E = mc&#178;</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like HTML in the  tag:

```
     Widget<sup>TM</sup> Model 6100
```

Then you can try (tested on Chromium - it works on clicking):

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title> change the text of the title bar -- IE11, Chrome, Chromium only </title>
    <style>
       h1 {background-color:darkblue;color:dodgerblue}
        .short {font-size:5px}
         a  {height:40;font-family:Arial;background-color:darkgoldenrod;color:lime}
         a:hover {background-color:darkcyan;color:powderblue}
         a.bluedark { color:#4a4c79;}
    </style>
   <script language="JavaScript">
     function newTitle()
     {
      parent.document.title=document.getElementById('stuff').innerHTML;
     }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1 align="center"> Change Title Bar -- IE11, Chrome, Chromium Only </h1>
       <div align="center">
        <a class="bluedark" href="JavaScript:;" onClick="newTitle();return false" onFocus="this.blur()">
         <br /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Click to Change Title &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
       </a>
      <div id='stuff'>some &trade; stuff</div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I think `&trade;` is just a character.  You couldn't do arbitrary text, right?

Comment: The OP just needs `MC` letters.

Comment: And is there a UTF-8 character for `MC`?

Comment: This is a far too complicated way; you can simply include the character ™ as such in a `title` element.